# Do "equational theories" include sequents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, universal-algebra

In equational logic, which of the following best describes the term "equational theory"?

1. A collection of identities.
2. A collection of quasi-identities, by which I mean sequents of the form $\varphi_0, \cdots, \varphi_{n-1} \vdash \psi,$ where the greek letters represent equations.

For example, suppose I say: let $T$ denote the equational theory of groups. Does $T$ just include the identities of group theory, like $(xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$ or does it also include the *sequents,* like $xy = yx \vdash xxyy=yyxx$??

Comment: In logic, a "theory" for a set of extra-logical axioms is the set of propositions which can be derived from the axioms.  So I'd say it's the former.

Comment: You can see also : George Tourlakis, _Mathematical Logic_ (2008), that use *equational* (or calculational) proof style See pag.44 : "**1.4.7 Definition. (Theorems)** Any formula $A$ that appears in a $\Gamma$-proof is called a $\Gamma$-theorem. We write $\Gamma \vdash A$ to indicate this."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See as a reference Burris and Sankappanavar A Course in Universal Algebra (http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html) on page 92. An *equational theory* over some variable $X$ is a subset $\Sigma \subseteq \operatorname{Id}(X)$ if there is a class of algebra $K$ such that $\Sigma = \operatorname{Id}_K(X)$, where $\operatorname{Id}(X)$ is the set of all identities generated of a type $\mathcal{F}$ over a set of variables $X$.

Answer (score 1):

The denotation of "equation" and "equational" in such universal algebra nomenclature does not normally include *conditional* equations such as Horn formulas. See for example the excerpt below for standard nomenclature.

> We assume that a first-order language is correlated with each class of algebras of a given similarity type.
>
> A formula in such a language is *open* if it has no quantifiers. An open formula that is the disjunction of one equation with a (possibly empty) collection of negations of equations is called a *conditional equation* or *quasi-equation* or *strict universal Horn formula*.
>
> The universal closure of an open formula, a conditional equation, and an equation are called, respectively, a *universal sentence*,
> a *strict universal Horn sentence* or *quasi-identity*, and an *identity*.
>
> The class of all models (in a given similarity type) of a set of formulas (or, equivalently, a set of sentences), a set of open formulas (or, equivalently, a set of universal sentences), a set of conditional equations, and a set of equations, is called, respectively, an
> *elementary class*, a *universal class*, a *strict universal Horn class* or *quasi-variety*, and an *equational class* or *variety*.
>
> The set of all open formulas, all conditional equations, and all equations true of a class $\rm K$ of algebras is called the *open* or *universal theory*, the *conditional equational* or *strict universal Horn theory*, and the *equational theory* of $\rm K$. The equational theory of $\rm K$ is denoted by ${\scr Eq}(\rm K)$.

Excerpted from p. 3 of *Decision Problems for Equational Theories of Relation Algebras,* Issue 604
By H. Andréka, Steven R. Givant, I. Németi.